# R - new column with values assigned depending on month

Tags: r, date, assign, date-arithmetic, r-factor

I have a dataframe which contains a date column:

```
          date  t14  rh14
1   2013-05-01 14.8  56.5
2   2013-05-02 14.5  71.8
3   2013-05-03 17.5  40.3
4   2013-05-04 19.0  34.6
5   2013-05-05 21.4  45.3
```

in which the month of the date can be extracted (I used the following:)

```
date=as.Date(paste(df.date$year,df.date$month,df.date$day, sep="-"),format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Now I want a new column in my dataframe, which is a factor f depending on the month (January -> first value, etc)

```
factor=c(0.22,0.22,0.22,0.29,0.29,0.28,0.26,0.25,0.23,0.22,0.22,0.22)
```

Been looking for a solution for a while and still don't really know where to start. Still pretty new to R and programming in general. Any help would be appreciated a lot. Thanks in advance!

Comment: factor variable should have unique levels. Do you mean that yo want to aggregate Jan, Feb and March under same unique level of 0.22 for example?

Comment: What is the code `factor=c(0.22,0.22...)` supposed to mean? or is that just the unwanted output you get? (By the way, don't use a name like `factor`, it shadows the builtin of the same name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you already have month stored as a separate variable in the `df.date` data frame. If so, you could create a factor from it like so:

```
Haude.input$monthF <- factor(df.date$month, levels=1:12, labels=c(0.22,0.22,0.22,0.29,0.29,0.28,0.26,0.25,0.23,0.22,0.22,0.22))
```

However, your values seem better suited to a numeric variable rather than a factor (in R, 'factor' refers to something categorical). If that is in fact true, you could do:

```
values = c(0.22,0.22,0.22,0.29,0.29,0.28,0.26,0.25,0.23,0.22,0.22,0.22)
Haude.input$monthF <- values[df.date$month]
```

Comment: used the second version and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want the month stored as a separate variable? If you create the date object, you can format it as anything you like.

```
temp$date =as.Date(temp$date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
temp$month =format(temp$date, format="%B")
temp$month2 =format(temp$date, format="%m")
```

result:

```
> temp$month
[1] "May" "May" "May" "May" "May"
```

Or, as a number:

```
> temp$month2
[1] "05" "05" "05" "05" "05"
```

EDIT: it sounds like you want to look up the value from the factor list (probably call it something else, that term is already used in the R world). Then you can use the month value, as @JVL suggests, to look up, but you need to convert to an integer first. May will be 5, June will be seven and so forth.

```
 value_factor=c(0.22,0.22,0.22,0.29,0.29,0.28,0.26,0.25,0.23,0.22,0.22,0.22)
 value_factor[as.numeric(temp$month)]
```

For your data, it becomes

```
 f[as.numeric(temp$month)]
 [1] 0.29 0.29 0.29 0.29 0.29
```

Comment: Not exactly. I don't want the month in a new column, but the value of "factor" depending on the month, e.g. the fifth value (0.29) for every date within May. So that the dataframe is date/t14/rh14/factor

Comment: can't vote for useful answers (reputation too low), so I will spam a bit to thank you for the hint with avoiding the term "factor" :)